# ioArgs in Dojo 1.10, dojox DialogSimple

Tags: post, get, dojo

Got myself a bit of a problem (only occurring in Tomcat 8.5, but I'll need to handle it)...

I'm trying to open up a dojox.widget.DialogSimple, using an href, that has a long url/data string.  Setting the HREF on instantiation causes it to fail as a malformed URL, because it's too long.  So, I want to be able to do it as an xhrPost. Is there a way to set this up using the ioArgs property? I haven't been able to find any documentation giving examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  An over-long URL string for an HTTP "GET" can cause problems: [Web Services: maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request).  In general, the solution is to do a "POST" instead.

Would this solution work for you?

[Dojo - how to submit data using a Dialog form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837211/dojo-how-to-submit-data-using-a-dialog-form)

```
<div dojotype="dijit.Dialog" id="subscription" title="subscription form" execute="alert('Transmitted');">
  <form action="PATH_TO_PHP_PAGE" method="POST">
      <!--input widgets-->
      <!--submit button widgets-->
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi paulsm4.  Yeah, that would work, if it occurred only in one location in my application.  I have a generic function call that creates dialogs, that is used all over the application, and this is where the trouble lies.  I need to be able to handle it there... I'd like the dialog object to execute an xhrPost rather than a xhrGet....

Comment: You didn't mention that in your original post;)
Q: Why not create your own Dijit?  A Dojo widget is the combination of 1) .js + 2) .html.  It sounds like EXACTLY what you're looking for.  Here's a brief tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRTLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.rad.samptut.doc/tutorials/web/topics/dojo_lesson7.html